# when i am not worked upto 15 mins on my application then close my application. Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer, exit

I am Using Visual Studio 2015. create an Application Using VB.net
I have Required auto Exit Application. When i am not worked up-to 15 mins on my application then close my application.
Thanks

Comment: Feel free to try it! You got our permission.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? What's your error?

Comment: i am not Getting how to can i create this Function.
**Not working** is Important in this case.

Comment: And again: what did you try and where did you get trouble?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to your application to close automatically after 15 minutes of non-activity?  If so, look into the Application.Idle event.  It is raised when the application becomes idle.  In that event handler, set a timer for 15 minutes like @Amrita's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Public Class Form1
Dim app As Application

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    aTimer.Interval = 5000

    ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.  
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    ' Start the timer
    aTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

and on the raise event you can write like this...

```
Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

     'Environment.Exit(0) - closes without a problem

     'Application.Exit() - closes without a problem

     'closes without a problem.
     app.Exit()


    'Me.Close() - System.InvalidOperationException
 End Sub
```

Comment: I've only been coming here for this past few months but I don't think posting answers to questions that have no code is beneficial to SO. This web site is not a code writing service, members with questions need to post what they have tried, what is their problem or error, and a definitive, direct, question. Answering questions like this only encourages more questions like this. I apologise if my view does not meet that of others.

Comment: @video.baba FYI: See [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368291/1359668), and [this one too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions), etc.  Point is, there's no consensus about this, and more attention should be given to addressing the bad question than taking it out on the answerers.

Comment: @Steve Doggart. Good comment, I'll remember that in future. I hope ;-)